# Javascript Date, add milliseconds on constructor

Tags: javascript, date

I know that this kind of question is not really right, but I'm going out of my mind to try to solve it!
I'm trying to add 7 days to a today date. If I use

```
weekFromToday = new Date();
weekFromToday.setDate(weekFromToday.getDate()+7);
```

It's all okay, it returns 09/15.
If I use this code above:

```
var weekFromToday, day, date, month, year, dayNames, monthNames;
// Add 7 days time (added in milliseconds)
weekFromToday = new Date(today.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 100);
dayNames = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
// Collect the parts of the date to show on the page
day = dayNames[weekFromToday.getDay()];
date = weekFromToday.getDate();
month = monthNames[weekFromToday.getMonth()];
year = weekFromToday.getFullYear();
// Create the message
expiryMsg = 'Offer expires next ';
expiryMsg += day + '<br>(' + date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ')';
```

It returns to me 09/08 and I really can't understand why!!
Thank you guys!

Comment: Don't do that. Not all days are 24 hours long, over daylight saving boundaries one day has either 25 hours or 23 hours. So adding time will introduce difficult to find bugs that occur rarely but annoyingly. Much better to add days to the date and let the Date object work it out (which it does quite well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got to multiply by 1000 (not 100) to get milliseconds. The code below will get you a date a week from `today`:

```
weekFromToday = new Date(today.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue may be here:

```
weekFromToday = new Date(today.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 100);
```

You should multiply by 1000

```
weekFromToday = new Date(today.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```